# python http client module error / inconsistent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following output

> 301 Moved Permanently --- when using http.client
>
> 200 --- when using requests

URL handling "https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJpHN.jpg" passed as arg through command

What I expect is give me 200 status ok response.

This is the body

```
  if scheme == 'http':
       print('Ruuning in the http')
       conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.i.imgur.com")
       conn.request("GET", urlparse(url).path)
       conn_resp = conn.getresponse()
       body = conn_resp.read()
       print(conn_resp.status, conn_resp.reason, body)
```

When using the requests

```
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
  response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
  print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: `requests` follows redirects by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to hit imgur over `http`, but imgur redirects all its request to process over `https`.

Due to this redirect the issue is occurring.

`http` module doesnt inherently handle the redirects you need to handle the redirects, where as `requests` module handles these redirects by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the `http` module includes in its first sentence "It is normally not used directly." Unlike `requests` it doesn't action the 301 response and follow the redirection in the headers. It instead returns the 301, which you would have to process yourself.